# flockdb - Has anyone successfully build it from git and installed it

Tags: installation, graph-databases, flockdb

I tried building flockdb from the sources from git, but couldn't do it.  Am using Mac OSX 10.6 and getting lot of issues in thrift/boost installations.  Has anyone successfully build it  and installed it. Appreciate any pointer to information on doing this (except the one from flockdb git site).

Also, I don't know about Scala, but is there any readily available flockdb installation file to install it on Mac/Linux/Windows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I just successfully installed flockdb on an amazon/ec2 machine under Ubuntu 12.04.

#### Install Java 1.6

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk`

#### Install Thrift (http://code.google.com/p/thrudb/wiki/UbuntuInstallGuide)

- install build tools and thrift dependencies:
- `sudo apt-get -y install subversion g++ make flex bison python-dev libboost-dev libevent-dev automake pkg-config libtool make`
- download a copy of thrift 0.5.0 from: http://archive.apache.org/dist/incubator/thrift/0.5.0-incubating/
- `wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/incubator/thrift/0.5.0-incubating/thrift-0.5.0.tar.gz`
- `tar zxvf thrift-0.5.0.tar.gz; cd thrift-0.5.0`
- `./configure`
- `make`
- `sudo make install`
- Install ruby client
- `cd lib/rb/`
- `sudo ruby setup.rb config`
- `sudo ruby setup.rb install`

#### Install SBT

ref

- https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Setup
- http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.7.7/docs/Setup.html

steps

The sbt package is available from the Typesafe Debian Repository.

- Install the deb to add the typesafe debian repository to your list of approved sources.
- `wget http://apt.typesafe.com/repo-deb-build-0002.deb`
- `sudo dpkg -i repo-deb-build-0002.deb`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install sbt`
- download sbt launcher:
- `wget http://simple-build-tool.googlecode.com/files/sbt-launch-0.7.4.jar`
- `mv sbt-launch-0.7.4.jar ~/bin/sbt-launch.jar`
- create `~/bin/sbt` file and make it excutable:
- `java -Xmx512M -jar`dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"`
- `chmod u+x ~/bin/sbt`
- modify `~/.bashrc`: `export PATH=${PATH}:$HOME/bin`
- `source ~/.bashrc`

#### Get FlockDB

ref

- https://github.com/twitter/flockdb/blob/master/README.markdown
- https://github.com/twitter/flockdb/blob/master/doc/demo.markdown

steps

- `git clone https://github.com/twitter/flockdb.git`
- `cd flockdb`
- `sbt update`. You will see the outputs like below.

```
......
[info] == update ==
[success] Successful.
[info] 
[info] Total time: 213 s, completed Jan 7, 2013 11:02:48 PM
[info] 
[info] Total session time: 267 s, completed Jan 7, 2013 11:02:48 PM
[success] Build completed successfully.
```

- build package-dist without test first: `NO_TESTS=1 sbt package-dist`.  You will see the outputs like below.

```
......
[info] == package-dist ==
[info] Packaging ./dist/flockdb-3e351842.zip ...
[info] Packaging complete.
[info] == package-dist ==
[success] Successful.
[info] 
[info] Total time: 7 s, completed Jan 7, 2013 11:09:51 PM
[info] 
[info] Total session time: 8 s, completed Jan 7, 2013 11:09:51 PM
[success] Build completed successfully.
```

#### Install mysql-server

- `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, then setting env variables:
- `export DB_USERNAME="root"`
- `export DB_PASSWORD="password"`

#### Build FlockDB package-dist

- if all above succeed, `cd flockdb` and go ahead to try `sbt package-dist`.  You will see the outputs like below.

```
[info] Passed: : Total 265, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 265, Skipped 0
[info]  
[info] All tests PASSED.
[info] == test-finish ==
[info] 
[info] == test-cleanup ==
[info] == test-cleanup ==
[info] 
[info] == package-dist ==
[info] Packaging ./dist/flockdb-3e351842.zip ...
[info] Packaging complete.
[info] == package-dist ==
[success] Successful.
[info] 
[info] Total time: 137 s, completed Jan 7, 2013 11:47:54 PM
[info] 
[info] Total session time: 138 s, completed Jan 7, 2013 11:47:54 PM
[success] Build completed successfully.
```

#### Install gizzmo and start flockdb

Just follow the tutorial in twitter-flockdb: https://github.com/twitter/flockdb/blob/master/doc/demo.markdown

#### Install python client

- `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`
- `sudo python setup.py install` for below two python modules
- Install thrift python client: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/thrift/0.9.0
- Install flockdb python client: https://github.com/pyronicide/python-flockdb/blob/master/README.md

```
>>> import flockdb
>>> client = flockdb.Client("localhost", 7915, {
...     "follows": 1,
...     "blocks": 2,
...     })
>>> client.add(1, "follows", 2)
>>> client.remove(1, "follows", 2)
>>> client.get(1, "follows", None)
()
>>> client.add(1, "follows", 2)
>>> client.get(1, "follows", None)
(2,)
>>> client.get(None, "follows", 2)
(1,)
>>> client.get_all([(1, "follows", 2), (2, "follows", 3)])
[(2,), ()]
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into some issues too, but they were resolved when I made sure that I was using the exact versions for FlockDB's dependencies:

- java 1.6
- sbt 0.7.4
- thrift 0.5.0