# FlockDB setup failed with Exception for create_shard on localhost

Tags: exception, installation, flockdb

Everyone, I am trying to use flockdb. And I followed this guide to setup it, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14223067/1700490, everything went fine until I tried to start flockdb with "setup-env.sh", here is the exception:

`
./dist/flockdb/scripts/setup-env.sh

Killing any running flockdb...
Launching flockdb...
Creating shards...
1 
Exception for create_shard on localhost: Table 'flockdb_development.shards' doesn't exist: Table 'flockdb_development.shards' doesn't exist
Retrying 50 more times...
`

I don't know why this happen, and I know nothing about Scala, I searched on the internet but didn't find an answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: System environment is Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Did you run the update package? sbt update package-dist This update should finish successfully before you could run the script error free